# SELECT data from a table using an intermediate mapping table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have one mapping table, let us say `VW_MAPPING`.

`VW_MAPPING` has columns and data like this:

<kbd>**`Metric`**</kbd><kbd>**`Table`**</kbd>  
<kbd>`A`</kbd>     <kbd>`VW_A`</kbd>   
<kbd>`B`</kbd>     <kbd>`VW_B`</kbd>   
<kbd>`C`</kbd>     <kbd>`VW_C`</kbd>   
<kbd>`D`</kbd>     <kbd>`VW_D`</kbd>   
<kbd>`E`</kbd>     <kbd>`VW_E`</kbd>

Now I want to perform a **conditional SELECT**.
Like

```
when Metric = A then SELECT * FROM VW_A;

when Metric = B then SELECT * FROM VW_B;
```

> **i) All the tables have the same number of columns.**
>
> **ii)The underlying tables don't have the metric column**

Basically I will get the Metric value from an Input Form. So I want to show the data accordingly.  If `A` is given then I will show data from `VW_A`. And for which response we have to use which table that we will get from `VW_MAPPING`.

What I want is something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM variable_table_name;

variable_table_name = SELECT TABLE FROM VW_MAPPING WHERE METRIC = form input
```

This is the pseudo code

> **I cannot use PL/SQL.**

Comment: Do the tables holding the data have the same columns?

Comment: yes, all of them have 6 columns.

Comment: your format style is brilliant.

Comment: If all the tables look the same, then why do you have separate tables at all? Just make this one table with a metric column and you are done.

Comment: If you want it to be totally dynamic then you need to use the dynamic query.

Answer (score 1):

Although probably not the most efficient way, I would be inclined to do:

```
with v as (
      select 'A' as metric, a.* from vw_a a union all
      select 'B', b.* from vw_b b union all
      select 'C', c.* from vw_c c union all
      . . . 
     )
select v.*
from v
where metric = :metric;
```

That is, the mapping table is not actually useful.  Instead of a mapping table, you should have one table with all the metrics and an additional column that identifies the metric.  You can also do this using a view instead of a table.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you expecting?

```
    SELECT * FROM VW_A where Metric  in 
(selct Metric from VW_MAPPING);

SELECT * FROM VW_B where Metric  in 
(selct Metric from VW_MAPPING);
```

Comment: But the underlying tables don't contain that metric column

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this.

By far the best is to handle this in the user interface layer - the code behind your input form should decide which query to execute. This has a number of benefits: the code is much simpler, it will probably be faster, and your database does the "storing and modifying data" task, not the "react to user choices" task.

If you really can't do that, you can use a UNION

```
select * 
from VW_A
where metric = 'A'
union
select * 
from VW_A
where metric = 'B'
...
```

This embeds the decision in your query, rather than looking at your mapping table.

If you *really* want to use your mapping table, you'll need to use dynamic SQL, but you say that you can't use PL/SQL.

I'm not aware of any other options.

Comment: But the underlying tables don't contain that metric column.

Comment: Yes, handling this in code will be easier. But the form input is actually Microstrategy Prompt. So it will give me only the 'A' or 'B'. And I have to form a query accordingly using mapping table.